# What exactly does one do and not do as an independent US senator who "caucuses with the Democrats"?

Tags: united-states, senate, terminology, independent-politicians, caucus

Politico's June 15, 2023 [‘Blood on your hands’: Duckworth blasts Sinema for pilot training proposal](https://www.politico.com/news/2023/06/15/duckworth-sinema-pilot-training-rules-00102228) contains the following sentence:

> Sinema, who **caucuses with the Democrats**, did not immediately have any comment.

US Senator (Arizona) [Kyrsten Sinema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyrsten_Sinema) was a Democrat but in December 2022 became an Independent.

The phrase "Caucusing with the Democrats" has a certain poetic "ring" to it, like Van Halen's [Runnin' With The Devil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5txwFv-zYM).

**Question:** But from a strictly behavioral point of view, what specific activities constitutes "caucusing with the Democrats"?

Does it involve things like meetings? Cooperation/working together? Sharing information? Sharing funds or resources? The actual side of the isle that the Senator would physically sit on in the Senate chamber?

Are there any specific activities that would *preclude* their behavior being called "caucusing"? Voting patterns? Rhetoric? Campaign activities or avoidance thereof?

---

Potentially related in Politics SE:

- [Politico's "Sinema rakes in Pharma and finance cash..." A salient issue and an exceptional pattern of donations, or just cherry picking of statistics?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/69377/16047)
- [questions tagged [caucus]](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caucus)

Comment: There are several related questions on the site, but the only true duplicate was closed without receiving any answers as a duplicate of a related question that isn't really a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that to they get to vote on things that the Democratic party gets to vote on. For Sinema, that means Senate majority leader, committees, etc. For someone in the house, it means Speaker of the House if they're caucusing with the majority party and House Minority Leader if they're in the minority. There's no official list of things someone needs to do to caucus, but the rest of the caucus can kick someone out, or remove privileges, such as how Liz Chaney had leadership positions taken away. There also aren't much in the way of official rules about fund-raising (there's a lot of pressure on members of a party to fund-raise for the party, but it's mostly unwritten rules). Sinema and Sanders do share fundraising resources with the Democratic party.

Comment: Thanks for the expanded answer. While this is House not Senate, to your point on funds sharing: [Do US House of Representatives members really need to "bring in a certain amount of donations, frankly, to get some top positions" on committees?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/77478/16047) (It seems everywhere I look "pay to play" is an integral part of the US democracy works (or doesn't))

Comment: Technically, everybody in the House gets to vote for Speaker, but because it requires an outright majority to select the Speaker, the minority party is not going to get their choice unless members of the majority party defect.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the description of the party caucuses from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congressional_caucus#Party_caucuses_and_conferences_in_the_United_States_Congress)

> The largest caucuses are the party caucuses and conferences in the United States Congress, which are the partisan caucuses comprising all members of one house from one party (either the Democrats or the Republicans) in addition to any independent members who may caucus with either party. These are the House Democratic Caucus, House Republican Conference, Senate Democratic Caucus and Senate Republican Conference. The caucuses meet regularly in closed sessions for both the House of Representatives and the Senate to set legislative agendas, select committee members and chairs and hold elections to choose various floor leaders. They also oversee the four Hill committees, political party committees that work to elect members of their own party to Congress.

So when Sinema chooses to caucus with the Democrats, it means she'll participate in their meetings. Since she was previously a Democrat, it means little significant change to her participation in this process.

Comment: Is that *all* it means? To the question "What exactly does one do and not do..." the answer is "attend meetings" and nothing more?

Comment: Basically, although what's important is what they do in these meetings: select committee members, set the party agenda, etc.

Comment: As far as all the partisan operations in the Congress are concerned, she's a Democrat.

Comment: I don't know what "partisan operations" means exactly either. I read the news, I certainly understand that if one applied [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) to for example senator Sinema, it would return "roughly Democrat", but that's not what I asked about. Here I've asked for the actual behaviors, the details of what exactly one would do and not do as an independent US senator who "caucuses with the Democrats". I have not asked about how we should think about this particular senator, there may be others that "caucus with Democrats" as well.

Comment: It's just a term I made up for any of the processes in Congress that are oriented around parties. Like selecting the majority/minority leader, committee assignments.

Comment: Bernie Sanders is another Independent who caucuses with the Democrats. But he also ran for President as a Democrat.

Comment: As of December 16, 2022 "But unlike independent senators Bernie Sanders and Angus King who caucus with Democrats, Sinema said she won't attend weekly Democratic caucus meetings." From the Washington Post's [What does it mean to caucus with a party?](https://www.washingtonpost.com/video/politics/what-does-it-mean-to-caucus-with-a-party/2022/12/15/3a81c63e-aefd-4b67-82ce-92e3a7f75807_video.html)

Comment: While that may or may not still be true in mid 2023, it looks like "[attend meetings](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/79969/what-exactly-does-one-do-and-not-do-as-an-independent-us-senator-who-caucuses-w/79978#comment345707_79971)" is not necessarily the best characterization.

Comment: @uhoh Well, she *could* if she wanted to. If she doesn't, then it sounds like it's just rhetoric.

Answer (score -2):

The goal of politicians is to get elected and then reelected. By saying they are not Democrats, they hope to gain some votes from more conservative voters by being able to distance themselves from the more radical policies of the Democratic party. In reality they follow the party line and vote appropriately.

Comment: I wonder how many extra conservative voters Bernie gets by saying he's not Democrat?  And how distant is Bernie from the more radical policies of the Democratic party?

Comment: Kyrsten Sinema has collapsed in the polls since ceasing to be affiliated with the Democratic party and has greatly reduced her odds of being re-elected.